# Tomcat server type unavailable in Fedora 15 Eclipse package

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, vaadin

I have installed Tomcat server on my Fedora 15, I can run it, and it's avaible at the localhost:8080. Then I tryed adding it into eclipse, File->New->Servers->Server But the list is empty. I am reading this guide http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/getting-started.first-project.html And this is how it should be 
[image: musebe]
<sub>(source: [vaadin.com](http://vaadin.com/download/current/docs/book/img/intro/tomcat-startserver-2.png))</sub>

And this is how I see it 
[howiseeit http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/8320/38149731.png](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/8320/38149731.png)

Comment: what problem are you facing ?

Comment: @saugok The #1 image it HOW it is in tutorial, the #2 iamge is how I see it on my machine. I don't see a list of servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you don't have Eclipse WTP (Web Tools Project) installed. Try installing it on top of your Eclipse-Installation or get startet with the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers where this is already included.

Comment: figured this out by getting eclipse from eclipse site. I think Fedora doesnt ship WTP for some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In your first image.. .try to click Installed runtimes. Locate your tomcat installation directory and select it.

I think the server is not detected because it's either stopped or eclipse cannot find the installation directory.

Hope that helps. :)